# Python - Passing input (prompt) into Function

Tags: python, input, prompt

I am trying to create a function that receives input from a user, re-prompts until one character is entered. Strip() is used to removed whitespace so only characters are counted.

Here is my current code:

```
def inputSomething(prompt, errorMessage = 'Atleast one character must be used'):
while True:
   value = (prompt)
   Response = value.strip()
   if len(Response) >=1:
      print ('Valid')           

   else:
      print(errorMessage)
      continue

inputSomething(input('Enter str: '))
```

The problem I'm having is with the loop. Right now it loops the result infinitely. Should I not be using if else?

Comment: Could you please correct your indentation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `input` is outside the loop:

```
import sys

def inputSomething(prompt, errorMessage = 'Atleast one character must be used'):
        while True:
            value = input(prompt)
            Response = value.strip()
            if Response:
                print ('Valid')           
                return Response   
            else:
                print(errorMessage, file=sys.stderr)


something = inputSomething('Enter str: ')
```

Note that an empty string equates to `False`.

I was confused with recursion, because of the indentation used in your question.

Comment: Thank you! This did work but when input is incorrect the errorMessage repeats. I'm wanting it to loop and re-prompt the user.

Comment: Don't you think that using recursion or not, you need an input *inside* of the loop ?

Comment: Edited answer, see above

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
inputSomething(input('Enter str: '))
```

To:

```
inputSomething(lambda : input('Enter str: '))
```

And:

```
value = (prompt)
```

To:

```
value = prompt()
```

This way you pass a function and then call it, instead of passing the result of a called function.

Answer (score 0):

For future references, another way that also includes retries:

```
import sys

def inputSomething(prompt, retries = 2, errorMessage = 'Atleast one character must be used'):
    while retries > 0:
        value = input("Enter str: ")
        Response = value.strip()
        if Response:
            print ('Valid')
            retries -= 1
            continue
            #return Response
        else:
            print(errorMessage, file=sys.stderr)
            retries -= 1

inputSomething('prompt')
```